# How can I remove a set of pixels from a video with c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have code written that will take a video and output each frames pixel values to a text file, but what I’m having a hard time figuring out is out is how to remove a set of pixels (16x16 pixels section) of a video THEN output to a text file. I feel like I’m missing 1-3 lines of code that will do this.

Everything I’ve tried doesn’t compile.

```
​//get every data value per frame
​​for (int r = 0; r < frame.rows; r++)
​​{
    for (int c = 0; c < frame.cols; c++)
    {
   ​​​​     grayValue = frame.at<uchar>(r, c);
        output << grayValue << " ";
    }
  ​​​  output << endl << endl;
}
```

I get errors for everything I do. Something needs to be added to this loop to remove a 16x16 px of this video before it exports

Comment: What errors do you get? Please post the exact error message. Also, I am not clear what you mean by "removing" a set of pixels; copy then set them to zero in the original image? Suppress printing in the loop above?

Comment: How big is the frame? Where are the pixels in the frame? What do you mean by _remove_?

Comment: whats size of frame, channel of frame? remove as in mask the original frame and save the frame(large)? or save the masked content(small)?